# Incompatible Xamarin.iOS versions

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Today I started Xamarin Studio for Mac, which told me to install Visual Studio for Mac, which I of course did. 
Then I checked for updates on my Mac, and it tells me there are none, but when I try to build from Visual Studio 2015 from my Windows pc it tells me

`The installed Xamarin.iOS (version 10.8) on the Mac Unnamed Server (255.255.255.255) is not compatible with the local Xamarin.iOS (version 10.10). Double click here to select a new server.`

I have not done anything than installing Visual Studio for Mac. 
 
Do I have to uninstall Visual Studio for Mac again and install Xamarin Studio for Mac?

Or how can I come around this problem?

I have checked for updates on both Mac and pc.

Before installing Visual Studio for Mac, I could build just fine.

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac ships with Xamarin.iOS 10.10, so your challenge right now is to locate the 10.8 bits. Xamarin says you can ignore such warnings, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/

Comment: I really cannot understand a negative mark to an answer where I gave you a piece of info which could be useful for you and not only. I'll delete it.

Comment: @MauroPiccotti I did not give you any negative mark?

Comment: @LexLi I cannot build, so I can not just ignore the warning :( I tried following the guide, but I can not figure out how to find the 10.8 bits

Comment: @LasseMadsen excuse me, so it has been somebody else. Have a look if it could be useful, after I'll delete it again.

Comment: @MauroPiccotti I think so, as any help is welcome. So it must be something with my mac :( I think, I need to uninstall everything with Xamarin and reinstall it afterwards